# What do we call this property: there exists $n \geq 2$ such that $x^n=x$

Tags: ring-theory, terminology

Let $R$ denote a ring and suppose $x \in R$. If $x^2=x$, we call $x$ *idempotent*. If there exists $n \geq 2$ such that $x^n=0$, we call $x$ *nilpotent*.

Suppose there exists $n \geq 2$ such that $x^n = x$. What do we call this?

Comment: When $n = 3$ I like to call it *tridempotent*. That said, you might be interested in the following result (even if it doesn't give you a name for the property): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29590/a-condition-that-implies-commutativity

Comment: @B.D., cool theorem!

Comment: @user18921 To avoid any possible confusion: B.D $\ne$ Bill Dubuque

Comment: @MathGems Right; I certainly wasn't confused, but the answerer there does have the same initials as I do. I am http://mathoverflow.net/users/22971/benjamin-dickman

Comment: @B.D It's a small (alphabet) world.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to consider semigroups, not rings. An element $x$ generates the finite subsemigroup iff $x^{m+r}=x^m$ for some $m,r\in \mathbb{N}$. Such minimal $m$ and $r$ are called an index and a period resp. of $x$ (J.M.Howie, An Introduction to Semigroup Theory). So if $x^n=x$ you can call it a (periodic) element of index 1 and period $n-1$.

If the semigroup/ring is finite then  $x^n=x$ just when the subsemigroup, generated by $x$, is a subgroup. So $x$ is a group element. (Thanks to Zev Chonoles for his remark)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what the OP wants - after all, there are things that are elements of groups that *do not* have the property that $x^n=x$ for some $n$, so giving them such a name is incorrect. And (for example) idempotence is a boring/trivial condition for groups, while it is a very deep and important one for rings.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: You are right, thank you. I will correct my answer.